# How can i create an app that closes skype

Tags: android, android-service

How can I create an android app that closes Skype. So I can stop the Skype at my workplace and start it after leaving the workplace. 
I want to disable Skype through my application without manual intervention.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following-
To stop an application in android you can [kill the application's process](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#killProcess%28int%29) by `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());`  or

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses("com.skype.raider");
```

Now you need to write a [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) that will track you where you are actually and from this services kill the Skype process when you are at the workplace. 
You will need to add the [KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES) permission to your AndroidManifest.xml file.